# How to fix a paragraph tag overflowing on css column?

Tags: html, css

I have to make a responsive text that looks like a book. It means that the texts has to be in the same place doesn't matter how big screen is. I'm trying to use columns, but I can't even make the p tag stay inside screen.

```css
.page {
      background-color: #fff;
      width: 100%;
      height: 141.43vw;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
}

.text-column {
      text-align: justify;
      column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<section class="page text-column">
  <article>
   <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
      consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio eos placeat aliquid rem neque maxime animi repellat in molestias quos
      asperiores odit reprehenderit eaque quod commodi, esse mollitia dolor quidem. 
    </p>
  </article>
</section>
```

edit: added img

[image: printscreen from browser]

Comment: Do you mean that the words should not change position by resizing the screen?

Answer (score 3):

Can you please try with "column-count: 2;" to 'p', because you can not directly apply this css to super parent of the desired element.

```css
.page {
      background-color: #fff;
      width: 100%;
      height: 141.43vw;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
}

.text-column p {
      text-align: justify;
      column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<section class="page text-column">
  <article>
   <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
      consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio eos placeat aliquid rem neque maxime animi repellat in molestias quos
      asperiores odit reprehenderit eaque quod commodi, esse mollitia dolor quidem. 
    </p>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add this to your "p" tag CSS:

```
column-count: 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, to keep the text in the same position no matter what is the device used you need the keep the text size in place and the column width to have an **absolute width**, rather than a relative one.

Assuming that the font size is always the same, you can apply - as the user above said - the **column-count: 2;** to the **.text-column p** and also set a **width: 800px;**.

You will have to make the paragraph responsive for devices where the resolution is smaller than 800px. Usually, most devices have a screen size wider than 400px(half of the initial size, but 1 column now).

The only problem is that whenever the screen width falls below 800px, the paragraph width will instantly transform to a 400px width one. The following code will get this result:

```
.page {
      background-color: white;
      width: 100%;
      height: 141.43vw;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
}

.text-column p {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  column-count: 2;
  width: 800px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .text-column p {
  column-count: 1;
  width: 400px;
}
}
```

As I said below, keeping the position of the words exactly the same in a phrase or the page content unchanged no matter the device **requires absolute sizes**. The previously mentioned solution works when the page number is not too relevant.